# Programmatically getting UIComponents of a JSF view in bean's constructor

Tags: jsf-2

Imagine a JSF page with several components such as `<h:selectOneMenu>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<h:panelGrid>`, etc. Each component has an ID. Is there any method or technique by which I can get the components programmatically when the constructor of the bean is invoked?

Comment: "pragmatic" has a completely different meaning than "programmatic". Please consult a dictionary if you aren't sure about the spelling :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can get the component tree by [`FacesContext#getViewRoot()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getViewRoot%28%29) and find a particular component by ID by [`UIComponentBase#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29):

```
UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("someId");
// ...
```

However, the view root is not directly available in the bean's constructor per se. It might return `null` on GET requests to a view wherein the bean is not referenced in a view build time tag or attribute. It's however guaranteed to be available during the pre render view event.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

with

```
public void init() {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's not clear why you need to do this, but I can tell that this is more than often a code smell. I suggest to investigate if this is really the right solution for the concrete functional requirement you've had in mind. For clues and hints, see also [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used) and [How to use component binding in JSF right ? (request-scoped component in session scoped bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667927/how-to-use-component-binding-in-jsf-right-request-scoped-component-in-session).

Comment: This code works for me. But you have to specify full path to component for example "form:component1:someId"

Comment: @Mindaugas: that's correct if they are in turn inside a `NamingContainer`. See also the link to the javadoc of `findComponent()` in my answer.

Comment: @BalusC, your "unrelated" is the most valuable here!

Answer (score 3):

I tried your solution and it worked :). Here i just posting my answer that how i did it. Actually someone just asked me this question that can we get all the components inside a constructor when our page invoke, i.e., why i asked on this forum:). Here is my code

```
/** Creates a new instance of ExporterProfileUpdateRequestGrid */
public ExporterProfileUpdateRequestGrid() {

    session = ConnectionUtil.getCurrentSession();
    exporterProfileUpdateRequestList = new ArrayList<ExporterProfileUpdateRequest>();

    int test = selectedRadioButton;
    System.out.println();
    //getExporterProfileUpdateRequestGrid();

} //end of constructor

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    UIViewRoot viewRoot =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent component1 = viewRoot.findComponent("exporterProfileUpdateRequestGrid");  //form id
    HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm)component1;

    List<UIComponent> componentList = form.getChildren();

    for(int i=0; i<componentList.size(); i++) {

        UIComponent component = componentList.get(i);

        if (component instanceof Panel) {

            Panel myPanel = (Panel)component;

            List<UIComponent> panelComponentList = myPanel.getChildren();

            for(int j=0; j<panelComponentList.size(); j++) {

                UIComponent panelComponent = panelComponentList.get(j);

                System.out.println();


            }

             System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.println();

    } //end of for()

    UIComponent component2 = viewRoot.findComponent("panel1");   //null
    UIComponent component3 = viewRoot.findComponent("myTable");  // null

} //end of init
```

I want to ask that i got form(HtmlForm) here, but panel1 and myTable null, why? Although i get panel  and table by inspecting HtmlForm children, but why i can't get them directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

see this http://horrikhalid.com/2011/01/27/how-to-find-uicomponent-in-jsf/

```
public UIComponent findComponent(String id) {

UIComponent result = null;
UIComponent root = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
if (root != null) {
result = findComponent(root, id);
}
return result;

}

private UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent root, String id) {

UIComponent result = null;
if (root.getId().equals(id))
return root;

for (UIComponent child : root.getChildren()) {
if (child.getId().equals(id)) {
result = child;
break;
}
result = findComponent(child, id);
if (result != null)
break;
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the panel and the table are in form, try the following:

```
UIComponent component2 = viewRoot.findComponent("exporterProfileUpdateRequestGrid").findComponent("panel1");
```