# How to get total Tab count of Tabview

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dynamic Primefaces Tabview. How can i find total visible tab count? I have tabs with rendered property which binded to some variables. I want to get total rendered tab count.

```
<p:tab id="googleId" closable="true" title="Google" rendered="#{myController.renderGoogleTab}"/>

<p:tab id="facebookId" closable="true" title="Facebook" rendered="#{myController.renderFacebookTab}"/>
```

Comment: In server side, you just count the `boolean value`. In client side, you can get via `javascript` by counting via `css` or `id`.

Comment: @RongNK how can I get Tabs from server side?

Comment: By counting your boolean variable, `if myController.renderGoogleTa = true then count++`.

Comment: I have nearly 100 tabs but its ok a Map resolve my problem. thanks for your help by the way

Comment: You can get tabView by id in bean, and just count the chidlens of tabView. You should answer to close your question :)

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8509590/1834700

Answer (score 0):

a Map resolved the problem. just count the "true" values in map.
private Map tabRenders = new HashMap();