# JSF button action triggered twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly

I already asked this question in the WildFly forum but did not get any answers so far. So I´m trying here.

Since I upgraded from WildFly 8.1 to 8.2 I have problems with a commandButton inside a tabView connected to a bean.

Here is a simple JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:tabView binding="#{testBean.tabView}">
                <p:tab title="Tab">
                    <p:commandButton value="Inside" action="#{testBean.testInside}"/>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
            <p:commandButton value="Outside" action="#{testBean.testOutside}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and the bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private TabView tabView = new TabView();

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
        this.tabView = tabView;
    }

    public void testInside() {
        System.out.println("inside");
    }

    public void testOutside() {
        System.out.println("outside");
    }
}
```

Clicking the "Inside" button triggers `testInside()` **two** times. The "Outside" button (outside of the tabView) behaves normally and triggers it´s method only once. Removing the tabView binding eliminates the problem. I´m using PrimeFaces 4.0.

Thanks for any ideas

Jan

Comment: Why is the binding (`binding="#{testBean.tabView}"`) needed at all?

Comment: The binding is needed in the real application because the tabs are generated dynamically.

Comment: Can you try this minimal application with a newer PF version and check if it still happens?

Comment: @BalusC you said "Components are request scoped, yet you're binding it to a session scoped bean", does that mean that we should always use binding with request scoped beans.?

Comment: I think that i found some answers here in SO, that may also help the OP (attached links in BalusC answer are also very useful):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667927/how-to-use-component-binding-in-jsf-right-request-scoped-component-in-session

Comment: @BalusC in some of your answers you said that Faces messages are request scoped and now components, is this because they are stored in the viewState ? i have tried to learn how they are request scoped from the code source but didn't succeed

Comment: @BalusC So what caused the components or Faces messages to be request scoped ?

Comment: @BalusC I understand the reason that it must be request scoped, but i just want to understand how they are request scoped in the code source? as even in the documentation i can't find that kind of information

Comment: Ah yes, i am reading its spec now,Thank you @BalusC for your attention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [Mojarra 'issue'](https://developer.jboss.org/message/915611#915611), introduced by a performance optimization fix in 2.2.7.

> this is a Mojarra "issue", I've discovered it when working on RF-13920, it was introduced by JAVASERVERFACES-3193. The components that use binding are not recreated during a request to the server but their children are. With the original children still in place inserting the new children causes the "duplicate id" error.

So it looks like your button is added twice, but since you do not have an explicit id assigned, you do not get the duplicate id error... Might be interesting to give that a try (adding an explicit id)

> The JSF specification states that binding should only be used in Request scope, so I don't think it should be treated as a bug if this fails in Conversation scope.

The last remark is the interesting one. As is posted in the next post on the jboss site:

> But now I think I have a satisfying solution for this issue and I can confirm, that with request-scoped backing beans for the component binding the exception and duplicate id problem does not occur anymore, even with Mojarra 2.2.8 from Wildfly-8.2.0.Final!
>
> This is even true if the rest of the logic for the page remains in a (say) conversation scoped bean. You just need to have a request-scoped bean for the binding attribute, which then can be referenced in EL and other beans.

Check also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667927/how-to-use-component-binding-in-jsf-right-request-scoped-component-in-session)

Comment: You are right, Assigning an id results in the duplicate id error. I will try to get along with Request scope or abandon the binding as BalusC suggested.

Comment: using mojarra 2.2.6 fixed my problem

Comment: yes unfortunately , I couldn't afford to refactor the code, downgrading seems working some how, though i am facing troubles with binding backbean of ViewScope

Comment: Bad choice... Bite the Apple and refactor... Always the netter choice. Especially since now you run into different issues @ameen

Comment: you are right - but it is a lot and the task is time limited and already violated

Answer (score -3):

You can try doing in other way. Use remoteCommand out of the tab with the same action of the commandButton. 
Then use the JavaScript function created by the remoteCommand in the onclick event of the commandButton. 
Here is the example using your code.

 It's functional.

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand id="myfun" name="myfun" action="#{testBean.testInside}" />
    <p:tabView binding="#{testBean.tabView}">
        <p:tab title="Tab">
            <p:commandButton value="Inside" onclick="myfun();"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Sure, but if you have 6 tabs, with 6 different buttons you need 6 remote commands. And using a commandButton in this case is also 'wrong', you should use a commandButton with `type="button"`... This solution is introducing more complexity then needed by doing it 'right'