# Is it possible to get UIComponent from a subview?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uicomponents

I have the following facelet:

```
<h:form id="submitForm">
    <ui:include src="/inc.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="bean" value="#{helloBean}" /> 
    </ui:include>

    <ui:include src="/inc.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="bean" value="#{myBean}" /> 
    </ui:include>

    <h:commandButton />

</h:form>
```

Where `inc.xhtml`:

```
<f:subview xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

      <h:inputText id="val" value="#{bean.p}" converter="conv"/>

</f:subview>
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509270/programmatically-getting-uicomponents-of-a-jsf-view-in-beans-constructor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378437/find-component-by-id-in-jsf) answers wasn't helpful because in my case there's the converter which I tried to write:

```
@FacesConverter("conv")
public class ProducerConveter implements Converter{

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        UIInput c = (UIInput) arg0.getViewRoot().findComponent("submitForm:val") ;
        Object val = c.getValue();  //NPE
        //convertion itself involving the val Object
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2){
        return ((Producer) arg2).getProducer();
    }

}
```

Later on, I've noticed that it's impossible for the implementation to decide which component I wanted to retrieve (from the first include or from the second one).

Is it even possible to get the component from the second include?

***Update:***
After some debugging, I figured out that the actual name of the component from the second include was `submitForm:j_idt5:val`. Is there a way to specify the id explicitly for any inlclude instead of `j_idt5`?

Comment: `<f:subview>` is a naming container. Assign it an `id` and prepend this `id` while searching its children.

Comment: @Tiny Don't see how it will solve the problem. I still don't distinguish the input from the first include and from the second one.

Comment: @Tiny BTW, I just did what you proposed and got an expcetion about duplicating id. Because I have including the same subview twice.

Comment: I don't know the function requirement of yours but it appears that you are looking for a reusable input component. I would have potentially gone with a composite component, If I had needed a reusable component.

Comment: @Tiny No, I just misunderstood what you said... I specified the id attribute to be replaced as a parameter: `<ui:include name="id" value="firstInc" />`. But honestly I don't exactly understand what it works. The id attribute is being resolved at the view build phase, so the attrbutes specified by `ui:include` are resolved at view built time too, right?